# passing generic object to a method in c#

Tags: c#, generics

I know this question sounds like it could be a duplicate, but I could not find anything related to what I am about to describe.

I am trying to build an html email templating project. I have a viewmodel (only calling them that for clarity that they are simply classes with properties necessary for that email to pass the values that need to be replaced in the template)

```
 public class EmailViewModels
{
    public class AccountClosedEmailViewModel
    {
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string RenewRegistrationUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccountReopenedEmailViewModel
    {
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string RenewRegistrationUrl { get; set; }
        public string CancelVerificationUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContactFormEmailViewModel
    {
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    }
    //rest removed for brevity
}
```

I want a method that takes an email view model, it could be any of those defined in the class above so I have a generic method to eliminate me having a BuildHtmlFromTemplate for each view model type.

```
public string BuildHtmlFromTemplate(templateFilePath, passing any one of the email viewmodels defined in the class)
{
    var temp = File.IO.ReadAllText(templateFilePath);
    temp.Replace("{username}", modelipassedin.username);
    //do rest
    return temp;

}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what you want do inside _BuildHtmlFromTemplate_? why not add function for every class?

Comment: Well, you could have a parameter of type `object`... but we don't know what the method is meant to do - what the code looks like. You could use reflection to find the properties, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet and using generic instead object `BuildHtmlFromTemplate<T>(T o)`

Comment: @Grundy: Well maybe - but only if that's actually *useful*, which we can't tell at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet, yep :-) need more info :-)

Comment: @dinotom, i not see `username` in `ContactFormEmailViewModel` what should happens in this case?

Comment: Thats a great point, and why originally I thought I needed a method for each class, which I still might. But i was trying to make the method work for all.

Comment: @JonSkeet, is it same used reflection from _object_ and used reflection from type as generic parameters?

Comment: @Grundy: Pretty much. I can't see how generics could help in this case.

Comment: @JonSkeet, i mean if do _o.GetType().GetProperties()_ better than _typeof(T).GetProperties()_? only for this generics in this case

Comment: I think @Grundy is right, since each class has somewhat different properties they all need their own BuildHtml method. I'm not sure its worth the time and effort to try to make it work for all

Comment: I really don't understand what's with downvoting inheritance posts but I think you should at least consider using something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection and generics like this

```
public string BuildHtmlFromTemplate<T>(templateFilePath, T o)
{
    var temp = File.IO.ReadAllText(templateFilePath);
    foreach(var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties()){
        temp = temp.Replace("{"+prop.Name+"}", prop.GetValue(o));
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Or without generics

```
public string BuildHtmlFromTemplate(templateFilePath, object o)
{
    var temp = File.IO.ReadAllText(templateFilePath);
    foreach(var prop in o.GetType().GetProperties()){
        temp = temp.Replace("{"+prop.Name+"}", prop.GetValue(o));
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Generics bring nothing useful in this case.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek, yep, instead can use _object_ and _o.GetType()_ instead _typeof(T)_

Comment: Generics approach with `typeof(T)` might fail if you don't know the exact type at compile type (i.e. if passing a base class or `object`).

Comment: @Groo, added sample without generics

Comment: @Grundy  very simple design. I've never seen something like the {"+prop.Name+"} what are the +'s for?

Comment: @dinotom, here just create string like in your sample: if `prop.Name=="username`, then generated string - `"{username}"`

Comment: @Grundy ah I see so if my class property is UserName, and the placeholder in the template is {username} use it like this? "{"+prop.Name.ToLower()+"}"

Comment: @dinotom, yes, like this

Comment: Ok im testing this approach, but resharper says prop.GetValue(o) needs ToString....temp = temp.Replace("{" + prop.Name.ToLower() + "}", prop.GetValue(o).ToString());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96968/discussion-between-grundy-and-dinotom).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to access object properties by name, regardless of their type, then you can either:

1. Use reflection, or
2. Turn all classes into dictionaries.

To get the value of a property by its name using reflection, you would use something like:

```
public static object GetValue(this object @this, string property)
{
    return @this.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(@this, null);
}
```

You could then use a regex to match and replace placeholders at once:

```
var inputHtml = @"<h1>{title}</h1> <p>{text}</p>";
var instance = new
{
    title = "some title",
    text = "some text"
};

// note: not much error checking here, and
// placeholder casing is important 

var regex = new Regex("{(.*?)}");
var outputHtml = regex.Replace(inputHtml, m =>
{
    var placeholder = m.Groups[1].Value;

    var prop = instance.GetType().GetProperty(placeholder);
    if (prop == null)
        return "";

    return prop.GetValue(instance).ToString();
});
```

For the second approach, you simply store your data as `KeyValuePair<string, string>` and do some simple string replacement.

Comment: interesting thought on dictionaries. I suppose I could have the placeholder as the key and the associated model property as its value and just loop through the pairs

Comment: @dinotom: yes, that's the most weakly typed solution, and avoids the need for reflection. But it also simplifies data entry (i.e. you could simply have a table with "name" and "value" columns to enter a bunch of values).

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of having a method in the class return a dictionary where the property name as string is the key, and the property value as the value and pass that dictionary to the BuildHtmlMethod. i would have to adjust my templates so the placeholders exactly matched the the class property names. Will that work?

Comment: @dinotom: yes, but I don't see a point in doing that manually for each class. And the functionality doesn't seem like it [belongs inside the actual classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). If you still want to have strongly typed classes, then use reflection and you're done. Also, if your templates have to be case insensitive, you can easily convert the property names to lower case while replacing, as long as everyone in the team is aware of the convention.

Comment: Grundy's answer (the second one, using an `object`) does a similar thing, and it's simpler than a regex (just change `prop.Name` into `prop.Name.ToLower()`), the only issue might be additional allocations on each `Replace` which shouldn't be an issue unless your templates are really large and have many placeholders.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class EmailViewModel
{
  public string ToHTMLString()
  {
     //And use reflection on the properties here.
  }
}

public class AccountClosedEmailViewModel:EmailViewModel    {
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string RenewRegistrationUrl { get; set; }
}

public class AccountReopenedEmailViewModel:EmailViewModel{
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string RenewRegistrationUrl { get; set; }
    public string CancelVerificationUrl { get; set; }
}

public class ContactFormEmailViewModel:EmailViewModel    {
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
}
```

Edit:
And this way you can move some of the common properties in the base class in order to make each model a bit lighter.